# What are these numbers next to the review button?

Tags: bug

In the past, I had some numbers to the left of the review button when there was something to review.

[image]

Recently I passed 2000 reputation and there are constantly 3 or 4 items in the review queue. But when I click the number, nothing shows up. I know there is now a "Tools" tab, but I don't see any tasks that would indicate the "4" showing up next to the review button.

[image]

Comment: Same for me, too. Not sure why, but I'll ask some moderators of older Exchanges if they know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons this happens:

1. The numbers at the top are cached and therefore may always be slightly out of date
2. You may have skipped an item earlier. In that case you don't have access to it, but it may still show as an item in the counter.
3. You may have reviewed it, but it is waiting to be completed (perhaps it needs a second vote)

There's a more extensive answer in the [Meta Stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match).